# Google Cloud Rest API Authentication through Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-api-gateway

I invoking google cloud rest API from postman. As per google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create#iam-service-accounts-create-rest), I have created Service Account and download key json file and json file contents are as below

```
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myproject",
  "private_key_id": "<KeyID>",
  "private_key": "<Key>",
  "client_email": "my-account-dev@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<client_id>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "cert_url",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
```

I not sure, how to use above credentials while invoking google cloud rest api in **postman**.

E.g. Endpoint - Get list of all projects in given orgnization. Service Account has all necessary permission to read the data from all project.

`https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/projects`

I tried to use private key from credentials as postman as bearer token but did not work but got below error. I also checked [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) but it very confusing.

```
"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
```

Comment: The service account RSA private key is used to sign a JWT Assertion and then exchanged for an OAuth access token. You will need to use actual code to perform those steps.